# How to click on the aside / previous Table Cell (TD) in the same row using Selenium Webdriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, dynamic, automation, webdriver

I want to click on the Checkbox element which is present in the dynamic web table which has 3 static columns (CheckBox, Description, Link) and dynamic rows.

[image: Sample Image] 
I'm able to get the exact text of the description of the check box but I'm unable to click on the check box.

Here's the script I tried to achieve my expectation but didn't work. Might be a wrong approach.

```
WebElement dataTable = driver.findElement(By.id("table_id"));
List<WebElement> TDs = dataTable.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
for(WebElement td : TDs)
{
    if (!td.getText().trim().equals("text that i want to click on its checkbox"))
    continue;

    WebElement particularTd = td.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@type='checkbox']//preceding::input"));
    particularTd.click();
}
```

Could you tell me the right way to click on the check box?

Thanks,
Karunagara Pandi G

Comment: Can you please provide some more details with the html?

Comment: In the table, first column will be a checkbox and in the next column will have description. I have to check on the checkbox of the particular description. Here, both checkbox cell and the description cell are dynamic IDs. How to click on the particular checkbox?

Comment: Will be able to help you better if you can share screenshot of the section of the DOM you are working on

Comment: Image is not showing :(

Comment: @Ishan _...screenshot of the section of the DOM..._ won't help in constructing good answers. For canonical answers the relevant HTML is mandatory.

Comment: The HTML part, I have included in my last comment Debanjan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the td contains only the data.
What you can try is to navigate back to the immediate parent table-row (tr) containing table-data(td). Then searching for the input 'checkbox' there.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <center><input type='checkbox'/></center>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span>Cell Desc</span>
    </td>
  <td>
    <hyperlink>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

To click the checkbox you can use xpath:

```
//*[@text='Cell Desc']/ancestor::tr//input
```

To make the xpath dynamic you can fetch the value and use that value

```
 String value = "Cell Desc";
 String xpath = "//*[@text='" + value + "']/ancestor::tr//input";
```

Comment: the text is present under "span" tag which is present under "td" tag. so shall i use like //td/span[@text ='txt']/parent::tr/*[@type='checkbox'] ?

Comment: //*[@text ='txt']/ancestor::tr/*[@type='checkbox'] . Yeah, the actual idea is to navigate back to the tr , and then select the checkbox for that tr.

Comment: Didn't work. The actual table is looking like, <table><tr><td><center><input type='checkbox'/></center></td><td><span>Cell Desc</span></td><td><hyperlink></td></tr></table>. Similarly "n" of rows will be there. I need to click on the checkbox which Desc has "Offerred Item". How?

Comment: @Karunagara, I updated the xpath in the answer, try with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
This worked for me please try the below code:


for(WebElement td : TDs)
{
    if (td.getText().contains("Your Text")
    td.click;
}

//if you are unable to click with td.click; use below code

for(WebElement td : TDs)
{
    if (td.getText().contains("Your Text")
{
    WebElement particularTd = td.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@type='checkbox']//preceding::input"));
    particularTd.click()
}
}
```